# Email2Case mail replies for potential clients without an account

Tags: email2case

Using Email2Case with users with accounts is straightforward and simple, if you need to send an email reply, the "To" is the contact related to the case account.

We use a default "Anonymous" account in which we map the email2case created cases in case there's no account created for the sender's email, but if in this scenario we try to send an email reply, we're getting the anonymous account as the "To", and we're unable to edit it by manually typing the right mail.

How could we (If some client or potential client send us an inquiry about anything business related) reply to it within salesforce to the right email address?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when there's no account for the sender's email, do you create a Contact record  via a trigger and then assign that Contact to Case.contactId?

Comment: I will try that, and i do think is at least a valid approach, so kindly add it as an answer so i can approve it, i just thought the email2case implementation used a more automatic approach on that scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A good strategy to follow here is:

1. In your Case after insert trigger handler class ..
2. Where there is no Contact already created by SFDC inbound email-to-case for the `Case.suppliedEmail`
3. Create a Contact from the Case fields: the "anonymous accountid", `suppliedEmail`, `SuppliedName`, `suppliedPhone` - some cleverness is required here to split the `suppliedName` to `firstName` and `lastName` - That is, to deal with names like "Juan de la Cruz"
4. Update `Case.contactId` with the id of the inserted Contact

Do all of the above in a bulkified manner

Comment: In the end i came with a solution based on this and it worked out great, thanks a lot.